# Magento's theme hierarchy: base/ vs default/

Tags: magento, themes

In [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy) material I read about themes in magento.

I also talks about default/default folder, but it doesn't specify clearly which is on top of which.

So, if a have mythemepackage/default, default/default and base/default, is default/default reached while getting falledback from mythemepackage to base?

Comment: Alan Storm has an excellent post about themes and fallbacks here: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates

Comment: The answer is no. A custom package does not fallback to the default package. See the comments on Amit's answer for more information.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I have just tested it. It passed over the default folder.

Answer (score 1):

**[EDITED]**

NO,
If you have below package/theme

```
  1. mythemepackage/mytheme
  2. mythemepackage/default
  3. default/default
  4. base/default
```

and you have set the package to **mythemepackage** and default theme to **mytheme**.

Then Magento first check in **mythemepackage/mytheme** folder and if not found then check in **mythemepackage/default** and if still not found then look in **base/default**.

If not found, a rendering error will occur.

Comment: Not true. mythemepackage does not fall-back to default package. The correct order is: mythemepackage/mytheme <- mythemepackage/default <- base/default.

Comment: Actually in your case you haven't create mythemepackage/mytheme. if you have created it then still you need to define the default theme in Magento admin otherwise it goes to mythemepackage/default.

Comment: The fact is that a custom package (mythemepackage) will -never- fallback to the default package. When there is no custom theme, there is just one level of fallback. mythemepackage/default <- base/default.